# Encountering NullReferenceException although object attributes show values when highlighted, and the DbSet being accessed exists within the DbContext

Tags: c#, asp.net

Once I get to the context.SaveChanges(); line, I get the NullReferenceException. I do not encounter this exception with the DBContext in other sections of the code, only the block where the user is to add to shopping cart.

From Products.aspx.cs (where user can add products to cart)

```
protected void AddToCart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button btnAddToCart = (Button)sender;
            RepeaterItem item = (RepeaterItem)btnAddToCart.NamingContainer;
            Label errorMessageLabel = (Label)item.FindControl("errorMessageLabel");
            Label productIDLabel = (Label)item.FindControl("productIDLabel");
            int productid = Convert.ToInt32(productIDLabel.Text);
            TextBox quantityTextBox = (TextBox)item.FindControl("quantity");
            string username;

            if (Session["Username"] == null)
            {
                // User is not logged in, display an error message
                DisplayErrorMessage(errorMessageLabel, "You must be logged in to add products to the cart");
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                // Get the username from the session variable
                username = Session["Username"] as string;
            }

            using (var context = new AdagioDBContext())
            {
                if (quantityTextBox != null)
                {
                    string storedCommandArgument = quantityTextBox.Attributes["data-commandargument"];
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(storedCommandArgument) && storedCommandArgument.Equals("quantity_" + productid))
                    {
                        if (int.TryParse(quantityTextBox.Text, out int quantity))
                        {

                            var shoppingCartItem = new ShoppingCart
                            {
                                Username = username,
                                ProductID = productid,
                                Quantity = quantity
                            };

                            context.ShoppingCart.Add(shoppingCartItem);
                            context.SaveChanges(); // Save changes to DB

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            DisplayErrorMessage(errorMessageLabel, "Quantity must be a valid number.");
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        DisplayErrorMessage(errorMessageLabel, "Please provide a quantity.");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

As mentioned earlier, I get a NullReferenceException at the save changes line. However, I am able to perform the SaveChanges function just fine from other sections of the code without error.

From AddProduct.aspx.cs

```
protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Validate input fields
            if (int.TryParse(txtProductID.Text, out int productId) &&
                decimal.TryParse(txtPrice.Text, out decimal price))
            {
                // Get other field values
                string productName = txtProductName.Text;
                string description = txtDescription.Text;
                string imageUrl = txtImageUrl.Text;

                using (var context = new AdagioDBContext())
                {
                    // Checking to see if the product with the entered ID already exists in DB
                    var existingProduct = context.Product.SingleOrDefault(p => p.ProductID == productId);

                    if (existingProduct == null)
                    {
                        // If product doesn't exist, add a new one
                        var newProduct = new Product
                        {
                            ProductID = productId,
                            ProductName = productName,
                            Price = price,
                            Description = description,
                            ImageUrl = imageUrl
                        };

                        context.Product.Add(newProduct);
                        context.SaveChanges(); // Save changes to DB

                        // Redirect to the products page to show new product
                        Response.Redirect("Products.aspx");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        DisplayErrorMessage(errorMessageLabel, "Product with the same ID already exists.");
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                DisplayErrorMessage(errorMessageLabel, "Please enter valid values for Product ID and Price.");
            }
        }
```

and from Registration.aspx.cs

```
protected void btnRegister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Label6.Text = "Registration complete!";
            Label6.Visible = true;

            // Runs a check to see if the username already exists
            using (var context = new AdagioDBContext())
            {
                string username = TextBox1.Text;
                var existingUser = context.User.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Username == username);

                if (existingUser != null)
                {
                    // If username already exists, show an error message
                    Label6.Text = "Username already exists. Please choose a different username.";
                    Label6.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                    Label6.Visible = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    DateTime dateOfBirth;
                    if (DateTime.TryParse(TextBox4.Text, out dateOfBirth))
                    {
                        int age = DateTime.Now.Year - dateOfBirth.Year;
                        if (dateOfBirth > DateTime.Now.AddYears(-age)) age--;

                        if (age < 18)
                        {
                            // If user is under 18, show an error message
                            Label6.Text = "You must be at least 18 years old to register.";
                            Label6.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                            Label6.Visible = true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // If agge is valid, proceed with registration
                            User newUser = new User
                            {
                                Username = username,
                                Password = TextBox2.Text,
                                Email = TextBox5.Text,
                                UserType = "customer", // Default value
                                DateOfBirth = dateOfBirth
                            };

                            context.User.Add(newUser);
                            context.SaveChanges();

                            // If registration is successful, set the session variable with
                            // text from TextBox1 since it contains the username
                            Session["Username"] = TextBox1.Text;
                            
                            // Theb, redirect to the My Account page
                             Response.Redirect("Account.aspx");
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // If date format is invalid, show an error message
                        Label6.Text = "Invalid date format. Please use the format 'MM/dd/yyyy'.";
                        Label6.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                        Label6.Visible = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I encounter no issue with these two other instances of using SaveChanges();

Here is the DBContext for reference as well:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace EC1_ContinuousAssessment
{
    public class AdagioDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Product> Product { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ShoppingCart> ShoppingCart { get; set; }
        public DbSet<CheckoutOrder> CheckoutOrder { get; set; }
        public DbSet<OrderItem> OrderItem { get; set; }
        public DbSet<User> User { get; set; }

        // Constructor to specify the connection string
        public AdagioDBContext() : base("name=AdagioMgmtEntities")
        {
            // Initialize DbSet properties
        }
    }
}
```

So far, I have tried placing the "using" line where the context is created after the ShoppingCart item is created, as well as placing the "using" line outside before all checks are made but to no avail.

The exception message:

```
System.NullReferenceException
  HResult=0x80004003
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=<Cannot evaluate the exception source>
  StackTrace:
<Cannot evaluate the exception stack trace>

  This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    [External Code]
    EC1_ContinuousAssessment.Products.AddToCart_Click(object, System.EventArgs) in Products.aspx.cs
```

The .aspx code

```
<%@ Page Title="Products" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Products.aspx.cs" Inherits="EC1_ContinuousAssessment.Products" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <h2>Catalogue</h2>
    <hr />
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" class="lead">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <div class="row" style="font-family: 'Raleway';">
                <asp:Repeater ID="productRepeater" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="productRepeater_ItemDataBound">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <div class="col col-md-4">
                            <a href="#" class="product-link" data-toggle="modal" data-target='<%# "#productModal" + Eval("ProductID") %>'>
                                <img src='<%# "Content/images/" + Eval("ImageUrl") %>' width="300" height="300" class="center-block img-fluid" />
                            </a>
                            <div class="product-details">
                                <p>
                                    &nbsp;
                                </p>
                                <p class="text-center"
                                    style="text-transform: capitalize; font-size: .85em; font-weight: 600; line-height: 1.5em; color: #212121; text-decoration: none;">
                                    <%# Eval("ProductName") %> - $<%# Eval("Price", "{0:0.00}") %>
                                </p>
                                <p><%# Eval("Description") %></p>
                                <p>&nbsp;</p>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="quantity" runat="server" Text="1" CssClass="quantity-input"
                                    data-productid='<%# Eval("ProductID") %>'
                                    Style="width: 95px"
                                    data-commandargument='<%# "quantity_" + Eval("ProductID") %>' />
                                <asp:Label ID="productIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ProductID") %>' Visible="false" />

                                <p>&nbsp;</p>
                                <asp:Button ID="btnAddToCart" runat="server" Text="Add to Cart" OnClick="AddToCart_Click" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" Style="border-style: none; border-color: inherit; border-width: medium; background-color: #CC0000; color: #FFFFFF; font-style: italic; margin-top: 0px;" />
                                <p>&nbsp;</p>
                                <asp:Button ID="btnUpdateProduct" runat="server" Text="Update Product" OnClick="btnUpdateProduct_Click"
                                    CommandName="UpdateProduct" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ProductID") %>'
                                    class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" Style="border-style: none; border-color: inherit; border-width: medium; background-color: #CC0000; color: #FFFFFF; font-style: italic; margin-top: 0px;" />
                                <p>&nbsp;</p>
                                <asp:Button ID="btnDeleteProduct" runat="server" Text="Delete Product" ForeColor="Red" OnClick="btnDeleteProduct_Click"
                                    CommandName="DeleteProduct" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ProductID") %>' OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this product?');"
                                    class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" Style="border-style: none; border-color: inherit; border-width: medium; background-color: #FFFFFF; color: #CC0000; font-style: italic; margin-top: 0px;" />

                                <div id='<%# "confirmation" + Eval("ProductID") %>' style="display: none; color: green;">Added to Cart</div>
                                <p>
                                    <asp:Label ID="errorMessageLabel" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" Visible="true"></asp:Label>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
            </div>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <div class="jumbotron" style="font-family: 'Raleway'; text-align: center; background-color: white;">
        <asp:Button ID="btnAddProduct" runat="server" Text="Add Product" OnClick="btnAddProductToDB_Click"
            class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" Style="border-style: none; border-color: inherit; border-width: medium; background-color: #CC0000; color: #FFFFFF; font-style: italic; margin-top: 0px;" />
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: SaveChanges isn't broken. We can't guess what's actually throwing the exception though because the exception text is missing. Post the actual full exception text, not just the exception name or message. You can easily get the exception text with `Exception.ToString()` or clicking on `Copy Details` in the exception popup while debugging.

Comment: The code needs a bit of cleanup too. There's no reason to even try saving if the arguments are invalid. You should verify the input *before* you start saving. *All* ASP.NET stacks (WebForms, MVC, Razor Pages, Blazor) have validator components that prevent submitting a form if the input is invalid. Check eg the [WebForms validation documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/a0z2h4sw(v=vs.100))

Comment: try restart your server and rebuild the binary. i have a hunch that it might not be the `context.SaveChanges()` that having null. something else, but the code and the binary in memory mismatched so the highlighted code is on that `context.SaveChanges()`.

Comment: Often the error is related to a required value in the DB, isn't provided in the object. 

For example, if you have DateOfBirth as not being allowed to be null, but isn't setting DateOfBirth in the instance you are trying to update. 

Sometimes the stacktrace provides you with the precise property, but sometimes you just have to compare your db table definition, with your objects content.

Comment: `string storedCommandArgument = quantityTextBox.Attributes["data-commandargument"];` is highly suspicious too, and probably the cause for the error. Forms work with fields, not element attributes. WebForms handlers run on the server where there are no HTML elements. WebForms isn't MVC and knows nothing about data attributes. It was created long before them

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I should have worded my query better. I figured SaveChanges wasn't the problem. What I'm trying to figure out is why the context object is coming up as null. Also, edited the post to reflect the full exception text via Copy Details. There are also validation checks to ensure no invalid input makes it through—the user can only enter a quantity from the webpage (which is checked to ensure only a number gets accepted), whereas the product id and username are pulled from the database and session respectively.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The "using" line was previously put after all checks had been made to ensure things don't get to that line without being fully valid. It was only moved outward in an attempt to match the AddProducts one that works just fine. The element attribute line you mentioned as well is there to identify the textbox on the page as the ID's are set dynamically. When I hover over the quantity variable that comes after, it shows the number that was inputted from the page so I'm not certain it would be the cause for error. All the variables show as having the correct data as well.

Comment: @MortenBork The object content and the DB table carry the same three attributes so I'm not sure what's wrong here. Also, when I hover over the object attributes after clicking the button, they all show the expected data: username = "testuser", productid = 2, quantity = 1. Then right below this, I call for the save.

Comment: @BagusTesa I've restarted the server a couple times now and done a clean rebuild but that hasn't solved it. I guess it's worth another shot anyway

Comment: @chamsyntana we can't look at your Visual Studio watch window. You *assume* what the error is by hovering, you don't know. Post the full exception text. Otherwise the question will be closed as lacking debug information

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Pardon my error in the last comment, it's not the actual ID's that are set dynamically. I set up the code in a way to dynamically assign the corresponding product id to each textbox. I can't do it with the actual ID attributes because that method conflicts with runat="server".

Comment: What you posted isn't the exception text, it's the crash event. The crash page would contain the full exception text. This also means the project has no error logging, which makes debugging or fixing production errors a lot harder, if not impossible

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I added the full text I got from clicking Copy Details like you said to the post. I'm also not assuming what the error is by hovering. I hover to check whether or not the valid data is in the variables, that's all.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.